# Print a specific letter of "ls -1" command [bash, sed, awk, grep]

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, awk, grep

Good day!

I was wondering how to print a specific letter of the following output:

```
ls -1 *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt
```

It gives:

```
Mcmm_E.txt
Mcmm_M.txt
Mmmm_E.txt
Mmmm_M.txt
```

And I want to obtain:

```
E
M
E
M
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. It prints the last-but-one field based on `_` and `.` as separators(assuming that you need to print everything between the last `_` and `.` and assuming that there is one instance of `.` in each file name)

```
ls -1 *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt | awk -F'_|\\.' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -1 *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt | cut -b6
```

Is a lot less typing than using awk...

`cut -b6` selects byte 6 of each line.

Comment: +1. To get a *fixed* character position, `cut` is indeed a better choice than `awk` (I've since deleted my fixed-position awk-based answer). However, generally speaking, since we're dealing with *text*, using `-c` rather than `-b` so as to specify a *character* rather than a *byte* position (which, depending on the locale, may NOT be the same) is preferable.

Comment: Just to demonstrate that `cut` can do more than fixed-position cutting: here's an (inefficient, but easy-to-grasp) two-step solution based on cutting out `fields` based on `delimiters`: `ls *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt | cut -d '_' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1`

Answer (score 2):

You should always avoid parsing `ls`; see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `find` instead:

```
find . -type f -name '*M[cm]mm*.txt' -print0
```

And if you have `gnu grep`, you could pipe into:

```
grep -oPz '[^_](?=.txt)'
```

Results:

```
E
E
M
M
```

Comment: You **only** avoid the pitfalls of `ls` if you (a) use `find` with `-print0` **and** (b) pipe output into a utility that is capable of parsing input based on the NUL character as the separator. While it's worth mentioning pitfalls associated with `ls`, it's equally worth  mentioning that the pitfall scenario - filenames with embedded newlines - is quite rare in real life. Furthermore, `find` doesn't output files in the same order as `ls` / globbing; even with `find`'s `-s` option the order may differ. (Cont'd in next comment).

Comment: If you truly wanted to avoid the pitfalls of `ls` in this case, simply use a `for` loop with *globbing*; in the case at hand:
`for f in *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt; do [[ $f =~ _([^_])\.txt$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done`
(I used the native `=~` bash regex operator to extract the character of interest, so as to avoid relying on `grep`'s `-P` flag, which, as you point out, is GNU-specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
ls -1 *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt | awk -F"[_.]" '{print $2}'
E
M
E
M
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse the output of `ls`. In your specific case, if you only want to print the *sixth* character of each file name matching your pattern, do:

```
files_ary=( *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt )
for f in "${files_ary[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${f:5:1}"
done
```

To only print the character in front of `.txt`, a funny possibility is:

```
files_ary=( *Mcmm*.txt *Mmmm*.txt )
for f in "${files_ary[@]%.txt}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${f: -1}"
done
```

These methods are 100% pure bash, and they will work even if you have funny symbols in the file names (spaces, newlines, etc.). Oh, and to be 100% safe, don't forget to use globs with `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 *Mcmm*txt *Mmmm*txt | sed -u "s/^.\{5\}\(.\).*/\1/"
```

-u for stream treatment (avoir buffering on huge folder)

I think `cut` will be faster

In this case, you don't take care of the first char even with a * in the ls